# Цвет текста определённой строки в textbox

Tags: c#

Можно ли как то сделать задать, цвет текста определённой строки, в textbox.

То есть, есть  текст:
Слон
клон
влон
хлон
кабзон

Нужно, что бы слон и хлон были синими, клон красным,а влон и кабзон сереневым

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте RichTextBox вместо TextBox и расширьте метод добавления текста.

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
   }
}
```

Соответственно, для вашей строки и RichTextBox'a box:

```
box.AppendText("слон", Color.Blue);
box.AppendText("клон", Color.Red);
box.AppendText("влон", Color.Green);
box.AppendText("хлон", Color.Blue);
box.AppendText("кабзон", Color.Green);
```

Поставил зеленый вместо сиреневого, не помню как сиреневый :)

Comment: А можно что-то типа box.AppendText("влон"+(a-Z), Color.Green);

Comment: улучшите extension method, все в ваших руках.